# C++ Sorting Players

Tags: c++

Several people are playing a game. Every player has a certain individual number of victories and losses (which might be equal or different). Write a program that prints the name and final result of each of them,.

Note: If there is a player with multiple attempts, the victories and losses are added to the final result.

Input
•   Until you receive the string "End", you are given the players’ information in the following order:
 - Name: string
 - Victories: a positive integer
 - Losses: a positive integer

```
  using namespace std;
  int main() {
    char str[100][20], t[20];
    int i, j;

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int first[100];
    int second[100];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      cout << " ";
      cin >> str[i];

      cin >> first[i];
      cin >> second[i];
    }

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (strcmp(str[j - 1], str[j]) > 0) {
          strcpy_s(t, str[j - 1]);
          strcpy_s(str[j - 1], str[j]);
          strcpy_s(str[j], t);
        }
      }
    }
    // cout << "\n Names Sorted in Alphabetical Order : \n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      cout << " ";
      cout << str[i] << endl;
      cout << first[i] - second[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: You forgot to add the [tag:homework] tag.

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Try Fiverr. But, what will you learn if someone else does it for you? Try! Code what you can, and, when you are really & truly stuck, post your code here & explain your problem, and we will help you. That way, you will learn.

Comment: Also, please paste your code as text, not an image. Thanks. In fact, please read [ask].

Comment: You also didn't ask a question. Rather, you posted a *problem* (one assigned to you). So what is your specific question for *us* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig  I did the alphabetical name order but i don't know how to print the results next to the name (Every player has a certain individual number of victories and losses (which might be equal or different). Write a program that prints the name and final result of each of them,.). I really don't understand how to do it.

Comment: That's belongs [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62229001/edit), along with the actual *code*, properly formatted as *text*. No one is going to hand-type your code in because they couldn't copy/paste it whilst testing their potential solution, nor debugging your potential problem(s).

Comment: Note: main reason to go from C to C++ is `std::string`. Why not using it?

Answer (score 1):

First, Your choice of data structures is questionable. You essentially have three arrays, side by side by side, that must all be maintained *together*  when modifying the "order" of any one of them. That is the crucial piece of logic missing in your code.

Second, you're utilizing *none* of the standard C++ library, save for IO operations. Although this can compile, and may even work, you're not fulfilling a key attribute of an *arbitrary* number of entries. You code assumes the first input is a count of players. Nowhere in the problem description is that assumption validated. You should be reading name,victories,losses as a trio *continuously* until `"End"` is read for the name and/or you reach eof on stdin (the latter is assumed but safely so). *Dynamic* storage is required, and the C++ standard library as a multitude of containers available to make that possible, the most common being `std::vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::string > names;
    std::vector< int > wins;
    std::vector< int > losses;

    std::string name;
    int win;
    int loss;

    while (std::cin >> name && (name != "End") && std::cin >> win >> loss)
    {
        names.emplace_back(name);
        wins.emplace_back(win);
        losses.emplace_back(loss);
    }

    size_t len = names.size();
    while (len-- > 0)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < len; ++j)
        {
            if (names[j + 1] < names[j])
            {
                // swap all three arrays
                std::swap(names[j + 1], names[j]);
                std::swap(wins[j + 1], wins[j]);
                std::swap(losses[j + 1], losses[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Names Sorted in Alphabetical Order:\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << names[i] << '\n';
        std::cout << wins[i] - losses[i] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note, this is *incredibly* non-maintainable. As more and more information is associated with each name (not just wins and losses, but perhaps home address, telephone number, playing style or position etc.) maintaining yet more arrays becomes a nightmare. Rather, you opt for an *object* to host all player information, and single container that holds instances of that object. No doubt you'll be learning more on that in your studies.

But in the meantime, the code above complies with the problem statement, while addressing the key piece of logic missing in your posted code. If you're going to swap names during sorting, you have to swap win/loss records as well, so the player in some arbitrary position `n` has their wins/losses come along for the ride.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful! But there is one more thing " Note: If there is a player with multiple attempts, the victories and losses are added to the final result." So if i type "Bob" twice it must print his name only once and also his overall result.

Comment: For example is this is the input Anna 3 3
Bob 3 4
Anna 1 0
Sam 8 2
Anna 1 5
Bob 3 1
End ... the output must be  Anna -3
Bob 1
Sam 5

Answer (score -3):

No wonder that someone will whine that it is a homework comment and not to help.
AJod Accrd i think that you need to do a public class and then do a map of string and pair of 2 integers